# Drag & drop uploader

Tags: javascript

I am  trying to make a Drag&Drop uploader. I've made the drag&drop part,
but now I have to make the PHP and I am stuck, without a clue what to do.
My problem is that, I cannot use move_uploaded_file(); because no

```
<input type="file">
```

is submitted. 
Is there a way to work around this and what should I be using/doing?

I am not asking for a full code example but just a clue to what's next for me.

Comment: For a really good implementation you can refer to [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/). It can be used with any server (PHP, Rails, Node.js ...) and is absolutely worth a look.

Comment: @ThomasKlemm I've looked at this before. But I just feel like it's not my page if I'm using another plugin, if you know what I mean. The whole page of mine is an image uploader. Maybe I'm just weird? ;o)

Comment: I totally understand that :D For learning's sake it's great to build stuff from scratch to get a feel for how those top-notch implementations work. As soon as you are on a project where the file uploading just needs to work and is not the actual value proposition you deliver, there are so many well-maintained plugins out there that will help you get your job done very well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [this implementation](https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/server/php.php#L33) to get an idea:

```
/**
 * Save the file to the specified path
 * @return boolean TRUE on success
 */
function save($path) {    
    $input = fopen("php://input", "r");
    $temp = tmpfile();
    $realSize = stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);

    if ($realSize != $this->getSize()){            
        return false;
    }

    $target = fopen($path, "w");        
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);

    return true;
}
```

I'm using such implementation in one of my projects:

```
$savePath = '/home/user/uploaded_files/picture.png';

if(!isset($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'])) {
    $input = fopen('php://input', 'r');
    $temp = tmpfile();
    stream_copy_to_stream($input, $temp);
    fclose($input);
    $target = fopen($savePath, 'w');
    fseek($temp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    stream_copy_to_stream($temp, $target);
    fclose($target);
} else {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['qqfile']['tmp_name'], $savePath);
}
```

Comment: Is it even possible to do this? I am reading lots of posts that this can't happen, because the file is saved on the server temporary. But I've thought of creating the file with php, and then trick it to upload the file?

Comment: It depends to method of file uploading. For example you can see [here](http://snag.gy/AYNLy.jpg) the GET request with additional headers `Content-Type:application/octet-stream`, `X-File-Name:family.jpg`, `X-Mime-Type:image/jpeg`, `X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest`. If you're using same technic, than yes, it is. As alternative you can use hidden [jQuery Form](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) to upload your files and then handle them at the server in regular way.

Comment: I've looked at your edit. And where would I get the tempFilePath from? There is no temp's?

Comment: `$tmpFilePath` is a path to file where you want to save the uploaded file. I'll edit to make it more clear.

Comment: Lol.. This actually works. I will make some changes, but this is a great place to start. Thanks a lot Evgeniy!

Comment: One more question.. I'm getting a damaged image now. Is this something I have to workaround or is this only occuring for me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17079/discussion-between-kolind-and-evgeniy-naydenov)

Answer (score -2):

With PHP you're most likely going to have to actually submit a form, even if it's done via javscript in a frame so that it doesn't actually move the page you're on.

Once you submit a real form you *will* be able to use `move_uploaded_file()`, just don't forget the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in the `form` tag!